# LESS CSS grid mixin

Tags: less

I have this piece of LESS code:

```
.generate-spans(@columns; @prefix; @current: 1) when (@current =< @columns) {
    .span-@{prefix}-@{current} {
        width: (@current/@columns*100%);
    }
    .generate-spans(@columns, @prefix, (@current + 1));
}

.generate-spans(12, "large");
```

It is suppose to generate something like this:

```
.span-large-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%%;
}

.span-large-2 
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
}
.....
```

But it just returns error: **Operation on an invalid type in ....**

How do i make the code work as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works in Less 1.7.0. Try it here: http://lesstester.com/

The only typo is the name in quotes, which you should remove:

```
.generate-spans(12, large);
```

And that fix might also make it work in the version of Less that you are using.

If for some reason you have to use quotes, you can also try:

```
.generate-spans(12, ~"large");
```

Which will remove the quotes from the resulting CSS.